Timeout in Dialogflow CX through Twilio Connect Virtual Agent
I have an integration of Dialogflow CX and Twilio Connect Virtual Agent (studio, voice). I want to set the timeout for inputs in my calls.
I measure the estimated waiting time and was near to 10 seconds, but I want to modify this and I don't find any resource or configuration to do this.
This is the widget that I use, the connection is works properly.
Widget Twilio
In Dialogflow CX I use the One-click Telephony Twilio Integration with my agent.
Integration in Dialogflow CX
I read the documentation, in the Configurations parameters in Connect Virtual Agent since Twilio I  tried to put this configuration, but it doesn´t work.
Configuration in Twilio Studio

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like the no speech timeout can only be set via the agent settings and not when initiating a connection to Dialogflow.
You can configure this by clicking on the agent settings for the agent, then under advanced speech settings you can update the no speech timeout[1] to be 10 seconds.
Hope it helps
[1] https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/advanced-speech#no-speech-timeout
